# sum function with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables Keyword and post

Keyword table looks like

```
       keyword    weight
         1         0.3
         2         0.5 
         3         0.4
```

for example

and post table

```
         post
       i am beautiful
       1, 2, 3
       1 + 3 = 4
```

if I want to sum of weight from the post table

which mean

I want to get result as

```
     post     total 
    1, 2, 3     1.2
    1 + 3 = 4   0.7
```

like this

should I use join clause??

```
 create procedure RankingPost8
 (@concept_name nvarchar(50))
 AS
 declare @k1 nvarchar(200) 
 select @k1 = keyword from keyword where concept_id = 
 (select Concept_ID from concept where @concept_name = Concept_name) 
 Select @K1 = coalesce(@k1 +' ','') + keyword  from keyword
 begin
 select id as Post_ID, post as Txt from Post 
  where freetext (post, @k1) 

 end
```

Comment: Why is the desired total for the post `1 + 3 = 4` the value `0.3` rather than 0.7?

Comment: this is sql server again right? mysql and sql server are two different rdbms.

Comment: oh sorry XD should be 0.7

Comment: yep but I think some of them are similar so :C...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use a cursor.

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE POST 
SET    TOTAL = 0 

DECLARE @keyword INT, 
        @weight  NUMERIC(4, 2) 
DECLARE CURS CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   KEYWORD 

OPEN CURS 

FETCH NEXT FROM CURS INTO @keyword, @weight 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE POST 
      SET    TOTAL = TOTAL + @weight 
      WHERE  CHARINDEX(CAST(@keyword AS VARCHAR(4)), POST) > 0 

      FETCH NEXT FROM CURS INTO @keyword, @weight 
  END 

CLOSE CURS 

DEALLOCATE CURS 

SELECT POST, 
       TOTAL 
FROM   POST 
WHERE  TOTAL > 0
```

A working example can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60679/5).

In my example I added a column to the Post table that holds the final value. If you want it in a different table or just in the output without changing the original table, just let me know.

Comment: Why do you need to use the SUM() function specifically?

Comment: My assignment required a ranking stored procedure 
Return a ranking table include Post_ID, Post and Rank
I have three tables, Concept, keywords, and Post

Comment: concept table has Concept id column and concept name
keywords table has concept id, keyword, weight
post table has post id, post

Comment: i could made a procedure which can figure out every posts including the keywords

Comment: I want to join clause to add sum of the weight with the table came from executing above stored procedure.. so..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
SELECT post, sum(weight)
FROM Post
INNER JOIN Keyword ON post LIKE '%'+ Convert(varchar,keyword) + '%'
GROUP BY post
```

Try it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60679/21).

I leave to you to add a where condition for your parameter :)

Hope you like it.